# Fiction book about a boy who finds out he has some kind of powers from another boy while at school and joins some government-like group with him

Tags: story-identification, books, powers

I read this book in middle school around 2013 maybe, about a 12-14 year old boy, (Boy A) who meets (Boy B) after somehow making a table flip with his mind in the cafeteria; (Boy B) tells him that he has some kind of powers and there's a facility with other kids like him who use some kind of chip to help concentrate those powers, to help them lift stuff, make fireballs, etc.. but (Boy A) starts to think the facility is not as good as it seems so he starts to retaliate. But they make his mom forget who he is so he can't go back home and decides its for the best after seeing his mom with a new boyfriend. The book also has a girl in it who is being used by the facility to pretend to be someone's daughter in order to find and capture him. The book ends with (Boy A) separating from the facility for good and being able to create a tornado without the chip, which is extremely difficult, even for the adults. I really want to find this book so please let me know!! :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember any details of the cover art?  Any descriptions of the characters or their names?

Comment: I cant remember any cover art or names of characters. I think (Boy b) was a red head or blonde, definitely a pale kid. (Boy A) had darker hair.

Comment: Were the children white? Brown? Canadian? Chinese? Blonde? Redheaded? Skinny? Fat? Was there romance? Did the boy only have the mother in his life?

Comment: I think the girl was POC but the two boys were white and boy A only had the mother cause the dad left or died. Definitely no romance between the kids,